# "on hold" - what happens with mailings

Tags: civimail, mailing

Given that a contact may have a number of email addresses, what happens if one of them are on hold (bounce) when that contact is to receive a mailing?

There may be a number of scenarios here, I suppose, depending on if one of them is marked specifically for use for mass mailings.

Does another address get used? If so, even if a special mass mailing address was indicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiviCRM will not try and send to an email address that is marked on hold (regardless of any other characteristics of that email (primary, bulk mailings).

If a contact has multiple email addresses and one or more of them is on hold, then CiviMail chooses the 'next' available email address and tries to sent to that.

More background here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/email/maintaining-healthy-email-lists/#what-do-i-do-if-an-address-is-put-on-hold